Is it possible to directly convert a PNG image to GLB format in Flutter?
I'm exploring options to convert a PNG image to the GLB format directly within my Flutter application. I've come across some online tools such as Aspose 3D Conversion and ImageToSTL that claim to perform this conversion.
However, I'm uncertain whether it's possible to achieve this conversion directly within a Flutter application. If direct conversion is not feasible, I'm interested in learning how to convert a 3D model created using a PNG image to the GLB format.
Could anyone provide guidance on whether it's possible to directly convert a PNG image to GLB format within Flutter? If not, I would appreciate any insights on how to perform this conversion using a library or package. Additionally, if there are any existing solutions or packages available, I would like to know how to integrate them into my Flutter project.
Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

We have logged an investigation ticket as THREEDNET-1525 in our issue tracking system to analyse this case of yours. We will look into its details and come up with suggestions and recommendations. Please spare us some time. I am Asad and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use Aspose.3D in flutter application.
But it's possible to write a ASP.NET-based web service with Aspose.3D to provide this feature.
Here's a sample code:
var imageFile = @"input.png";
var glbFile = @"output.glb";

// Read image for retrieving its size
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imageFile);
using var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes));

// Calculate the plane's size with the same ratio used in the image
var planeWidth = 20.0f;
var planeHeight = planeWidth / image.Height * image.Width;

// Create a plane with calculated size
var p = new Aspose.ThreeD.Entities.Plane()
{
    Width = planeWidth,
    Length = planeHeight
};

// Create a material instance with texture
var mat = new LambertMaterial();
var tex = new Texture()
{
    // Read image file into memory so we can save it to GLB later
    Content = bytes,
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(imageFile)
};
mat.SetTexture(Material.MapDiffuse, tex);

// Create a scene from the plane and attach the material to the plane's node
var scene = new Scene();
scene.RootNode.CreateChildNode(p).Material = mat;

// Save scene into a GLB file and embed the image into the GLB file
var opt = new GltfSaveOptions(FileContentType.Binary)
{
    EmbedAssets = true
};
scene.Save(glbFile, opt);

